# Evaluating this integral of the Coulomb interaction

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, potential-theory

I have the following definite integral over 6D space, in spherical coordinates:

$$\int d^3r d^3r' \frac{e^{-2a(r+r')}}{|\mathbf{r-r'}|}$$

I am unsure how to approch this but I have a couple of ideas.

The first is to use the Laplace expansion of $\frac{1}{|\mathbf{r-r'}|}$ in spherical harmonics.

The second is to look for an 6D coordinate system but I have not been able to find anything on commonly-used coordinate systems in $D>3$.

Comment: Have you tried expressing $\mathbf r’$ in spherical coordinates centered at $\mathbf r$? (Perhaps warm up doing this in $\Bbb R^2\times \Bbb R^2$?)

Comment: In that case the magnitude, r', will introduce trigonometric functions into the exponent.

Comment: Yes. And otherwise they’re crazily messy in the denominator!

Comment: It's a homogeneous function of degree $-5$ in $a$, so you're really looking for the rational $q$ and integer $n$ for which it is equal to $q\pi^{n/2}a^{-5}$ (which in turn can be found using Fourier transforms and the theory of the gamma function)

Comment: @KBDave I think you’d better turn that into a complete answer, or at least an almost complete one.

Comment: Guessing you're a physicist ... It looks like a double integral over $R^3$, not '6D space.'

Comment: @aruralreader what else would you call $\Bbb{R}^3\times\Bbb{R}^3$ ? Edited because I think I better understood your complaint

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let's denote
$$I(a)=\int d^3r_1 d^3r_2 \frac{e^{-2a(r_1+r_2)}}{|\mathbf{r_1-r_2}|}$$
Switching to the polar system of coordinate and choosing the direction of $\mathbf{r_2}$ as the polar axis in the system of coordinates of $\mathbf{r_1}$
$$I(a)=\int d^3r_2\int_0^\infty e^{-2a(r_1+r_2)}r_1^2dr_1\int_0^\pi\frac{\sin\theta_1d\theta_1}{\sqrt{r_1^2+r_2^2-2r_1r_2\cos\theta_1}}\int_0^{2\pi}d\phi_1$$
$$=8\pi^2\int_0^\infty r_2^2dr_2\int_0^\infty r_1^2dr_1\int_{-1}^1\frac {e^{-2a(r_1+r_2)}}{\sqrt{2r_1r_2}}\frac{dx}{\sqrt{\frac{r_1^2+r_2^2}{2r_1r_2}-x}}$$
Integrating with respect to $x$
$$=8\pi^2\int_0^\infty dr_2\int_0^\infty dr_1\frac{r_1^2r_2^2}{2r_1r_2}e^{-2a(r_1+r_2)}\big(r_1+r_2-|r_1-r_2|\big)$$
Making the substitution $r_1+r_2=x\,,\,\,r_1-r_2=y$
$$I(a)=\frac{\pi^2}2\int_0^\infty dx\int_{-x}^xdy(x+y)(x-y)e^{-2ax}\big(x-|y|\big)$$
$$=\pi^2\int_0^\infty e^{-2ax}dx\int_0^xdy(x^3-xy^2-x^2y+y^3)=\pi^2\frac5{12}\int_0^\infty e^{-2ax}x^4dx$$
$$\boxed{\,\,I(a)=\frac{5\pi^2}{16\,a^5}\,\,}$$

Comment: Great, thank you! How do you obtain the limits for the dy integral on the second last line? Also, I think you missed a factor of two on the third line.

Comment: Also, I think you missed a factor of two on the third line - 
$$\int d^3r_2=\int_0^{2\pi}d\phi_2\int_0^\pi \sin\theta_2 d\theta_2\int_0^\infty r_2^2dr_2=4\pi\int_0^\infty r_2^2dr_2$$
$$\int_0^{2\pi}d\phi_2=2\pi;\,\,\sin\theta_1d\theta_1=-d(\cos\theta_1)=-dx$$

Comment: How do you obtain the limits for the dy integral on the second last line? - 
Probably, the best option is to draw the picture. You integrate inside the first quarter of the plane (bounded by the positive parts of axes), and you change to integration along the median (from zero to infinity) and the line perpendicular to the median inside the limits from $-x$ to $x$ for every x

Comment: The answer I get when I compute it is $\frac{3\pi^2}{8a^5}$, not $\frac{5\pi^2}{16a^5}$

Comment: @Ninad Munshi, WA gives for the original integral https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=%5Cint_0%5E%5Cinfty+%5Cint_0%5E%5Cinfty+%5Cint_%7B-1%7D%5E1e%5E%7B-2%28y%2Bz%29%7Dy%5E2z%5E2%2F%28%5Csqrt%7By%5E2%2Bz%5E2-2xyz%7D%29dxdydz

Comment: e.i. $\int_0^\infty \int_0^\infty \int_{-1}^1e^{-2(y+z)}y^2z^2/(\sqrt{y^2+z^2-2xyz})dxdydz=\frac5{64}$ (I put $a=1$)

Comment: I trust your method more than mine. Looking at my work, there is a hidden degree of freedom. The gradient can have an extra unknown term of the form $\frac{C}{r^2}$ (or $\frac{C}{r}$ in $f$) that can contribute to the integral but still satisfy the vanishing boundary conditions. Other than computing the integral directly as you've done I don't know how to determine $C$.

Comment: @Ninad Munshi, I think you are right - the extra-term could contribute. Your approach is interesting and worth deeper investigation; from my end, I'll try to find out was is happening.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a PDE-centric approach. Denote

$$f(\mathbf{r}) = \int_{\Bbb{R}^3}d^3\mathbf{r}'\frac{e^{-2ar'}}{|\mathbf{r-r'}|}$$

Notice that this is the solution to the inhomogeneous Laplace equation, or in other words

$$\Delta f(\mathbf{r}) = 4\pi e^{-2ar}$$

And choosing $f$ to be purely radial, we can use

$$\Delta f(\mathbf{r}) = \Delta f(r) = \frac{1}{r^2}\frac{d}{dr}\left(r^2\frac{df}{dr}\right)$$

to compute $f(r)$:

$$\nabla f = \frac{4\pi\hat{\mathbf{r}}}{r^2}\int dr \:r^2e^{-2ar} = -\frac{\pi e^{-2ar}}{a^3}\left(2a^2+\frac{2a}{r}+\frac{1}{r^2}\right)\hat{\mathbf{r}}$$

$$\implies f = -\frac{\pi}{a^3}\int dr \:\left(2a^2e^{-2ar}\right)+\left(\frac{2ae^{-2ar}}{r}+\frac{e^{-2ar}}{r^2}\right) = \frac{\pi e^{-2ar}}{a^3}\left(a+\frac{1}{r}\right)$$

choosing all $+C$s to be zero to allow the functions to vanish as $r\to\infty$. Thus the integral we want is

$$U = \frac{\pi}{a^3}\int_{\Bbb{R}^3}d^3\mathbf{r}\:e^{-4ar}\left(a+\frac{1}{r}\right) = \frac{4\pi^2}{a^3}\int_0^\infty dr\:ar^2e^{-4ar}+re^{-4ar}$$
$$ = \frac{\pi^2}{a^5}\left(\frac{2!}{4^2}+\frac{1!}{4}\right) = \boxed{\frac{3\pi^2}{8a^5}}$$